# Proving nonexistence of local extrema of harmonic functions using Hessian

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, harmonic-functions, hessian-matrix

**Edited** I want to prove that solution to Laplace's equation do not support local maximum or minimum using Hessian.

Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ is a real-valued function of three real variables that satisfies the Laplace equation, $\nabla^2f=0$. Consider the Hessian matrix
$$
H(x,y,z)=
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{xx} & f_{xy} & f_{xz}\\
f_{yx} & f_{yy} & f_{yz}\\
f_{zx} & f_{zy} & f_{zz}\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is real symmetric. Therefore, its eigenvalues must all be real. Due to Laplace equation, $${\rm Tr}(H)=\nabla^2f=0.$$ So either (1) all eigenvalues are zero or (2) at least some of them must have mixed signs.

In case (2) i.e., when the eigenvalues have mixed signs, it follows that solutions to Laplace equation do not tolerate local maxima or minima.

In the case (1) i.e., when the eigenvalues are all zero, Hessian cannot tell us anything. Here, the test becomes inconclusive. How can I proceed, in this case, to continue with the proof of the fact that Laplace's equation do not support local maximum or local minimum?

Comment: In general, no we cannot, take $f=0$ for example. In what context does the question arise though? It depends on the function.

Comment: Another example would be any linear function

Comment: I have edited the language of the question because it was not clear what was I asking for.

Comment: a symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so it must be identically zero if the eigenvalues are all zero -this forces $f$ linear etc

Comment: @Conrad Can we say that the only possible solutions to the Laplace equation, f,  with all eigenvalues of the Hessian being zero are either f=constant or f is linear? If that's true, and can be proved, then it trivially true that in this case too, Laplace equation do not have local maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that your statement about the eigenvalues not being zero holds (consider e.g. constant or linear functions which have vanishing Hessian), but if you only want to exclude local extrema, then you can just use the [maximum principle for harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Maximum_principle). One possible formulation is the following:

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and connected. Then any harmonic function $u\in C^2(\overline{\Omega},\mathbb{R})$ is either constant or attains neither a local maximum nor a local minimum inside of $\Omega$.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer and more pin-pointed. Please let me know what you think about it.

Comment: @Solidification I do not think that the problem is solvable via the approach you are suggesting. The Hessian of a $C^2$-function only provides a sufficient criterion for the existence of an extremal value, not a necessary one: The functions $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ and $g(x,y)=x^3+y^3$ both have vanishing gradient at $(0,0)$, so they both could have a local minimum or maximum there. But the Hessians of both are not of use to us: They both vanish at $(0,0)$. Still, we can clearly see that $f$ has a local (even global) minimum at $(0,0)$, while $g$ only has a saddle point.

Comment: @Solidification Of course, neither $f$ nor $g$ are harmonic. As I stated in my answer, a harmonic function that is not constant will never have a local maximum or minimum.