# Possible to have only zero eigenvalues of the Hessian of a harmonic function that is neither of the form $ax+by+cz+d$ nor a constant?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, harmonic-functions, hessian-matrix

(Following an earlier post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882363)) I intuit that  if we restrict to functions $f(x,y,z)$ that are harmonic (i.e. satisfying $\nabla^2f=0)$ but neither of the form $ax+by+cz+d$ ($a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$) nor a constant, all the three eigenvalues of the $3\times 3$ Hessian matrix
$$
H(x,y,z)=
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{xx} & f_{xy} & f_{xz}\\
f_{yx} & f_{yy} & f_{yz}\\
f_{zx} & f_{zy} & f_{zz}\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
cannot all be zero. Of course, I don't have a proof. But does anyone have any counterexample?

Comment: The Hessian is symmetric, if all the eigenvalues are zero, then the Hessian is the zero matrix, which implies that the gradient is constant, which implies that $f$ is an affine function.

Comment: That is true. Examples are $f=$constant and linear $f$. Any other example possible?

Comment: Any affine function, like $f(x,y,z) = x+5$.

Comment: Of course. I included that into my definition of linear. So my intuition is right?

Comment: Do not call affine functions linear.

Comment: Okay. Let me edit the question a bit

Comment: My argument above only shows that we cannot have that all the eigenvalues of the Hessian are zero for all $(x,y,z)$. It does not rule out the possibility that this happens at some points.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Do you have any such example i.e. not affine yet Hessian has all zero eigenvalues at least at one point?

Comment: I do not know any such example. I am just saying that you want to specify what you are interested in.

Comment: I am interested in showing that the solutions to Laplace's equation in 3D, $\nabla^2f=0$, do not tolerate any local maximum or minimum. I know that this can be proved using the mean value property of the harmonic functions. But I want to prove it using the knowledge of Hessians. It turns out that for a Harmonic function, $f$, due to Laplace's equation, the trace of the Hessian ${\rm Tr}(H)=0$. Therefore, either all eigenvalues of zero or they have mixed signs. If they have mixed signs, then it follows that $f$ cannot have a local maximum or minimum.

Comment: On the other hand, when all eigenvalues are zero, the Hessian test fails. Now, if all eigenvalues are zero, the function is affine. Affine functions also do not have any local maximum or minimum. Right? So have I proved that Laplace equation do not have any local maximum or minimum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the precise formulation of the question.

**The Hessian vanishes everywhere:** In this case the function must be (locally) affine. Indeed, if the Hessian vanishes, then we have for every $j\in \{1,2,3\}$ that $$\nabla (\partial_j f)(x,y,z)=((\partial_1 \partial_j f)(x,y, z), (\partial_2 \partial_j f)(x,y,z), (\partial_3 \partial_j f)(x,y,z))=(0,0,0).$$ This means that $\partial_j f$ is (locally) constant. This implies that $f$ is (locally) affine.

**Hessian is only vanishing at certain points:** The function $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ is a counterexample to the claim "if $f$ is harmonic and the Hessian vanishes at least in one point, then $f$ must be an affine function". It is harmonic, we even have $\partial_j^2 f \equiv 0$ for all $j\in \{1,2,3\}$. However, we have
$$ Hf(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & z & y \\ z & 0 & x \\ y &x & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Thus, we get that $Hf(0,0,0)$ is the zero matrix.

Note that we also have $\nabla f(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)$ (it is also a critical point). Thus, if you are trying to show that harmonic function do not have local extrema, then you need to find a way to deal with the second case too.

Comment: But all three eigenvalues ate zero here. So this is not a counterexample.

Comment: @Solidification What do you mean? You are asking whether Hessian being the zero matrix at some point implies that the function must be affine... and the answer is no.

Comment: Otherwise you need to elaborate on what you are looking for.

Comment: Have you read the comment "I am interested... " and the comment following that? Should I make it part of the question to make the context clearer? I can do that.

Comment: @Solidification I have read it now and it is simply not true. My answer gives an example of a harmonic function which has a point where the Hessian vanishes (i.e. all eigenvalues are zero), but the function is not affine. In fact, it is even worse, the function I give above also has a critical point there. So your approach simply does not work. I do not understand what you are expecting more from an answer to your question.

Comment: I seem to have got it now. For a harmonic function, $Tr(H)=0$ at all points. This leads to three possible cases. All the eigenvalues are zero at all points, the eigenvalues have mixed signs at all points, and the last case, all eigenvalues are zero at some points and mixed signs at other points. Your function belongs to the last case. I erroneously missed the last. I think that harmonic together with the condition that all eigenvalues of the hessian are zero at all points implies affine function.

Comment: @Solidification Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Solidification That is exactly what Severin proved in his very first comment.  If this was your question all along, I suggest Severin replace their answer with their comment, and you accept it once you are happy with it.